# On change listener not fired for file input in browser action popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My browser action pop up has a file input, to which a "change" event listener is attached. Problem is, this listener isn't called when I chose file from popup using file chooser dialog, and the popup window is closed.
This doesn't repro when I inspect the popup window, and the listener is called since the window stays open. Now I am trying to find a way to have the change listener called, without needing to inspect the element.

There are no js errors in console. This is all I have in my window.onload

```
document.getElementById('initial_file').addEventListener('change', dummyFunction, false);
```

dummyFunction is defined (and executes if I keep the popup window open through inspecting)

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: Google chrome, this is an extension.